# How to give focus to a text box on page load for Safari mobile?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Is there a way to give focus to a text box on page load for Safari mobile (Ipad)? If not, would using Chrome for IOS work for this, or is it an IOS feature that prevents this, and not Safari?

Comment: If only it supported [autofocus](http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus) Did you try to set it with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I tried JavaScript, and it didn't work. From looking around the web, I've seen people saying it's a Safari thing, but I'm trying to confirm if it's a Safari issue, or an IOS issue, and if Chrome on IOS would be a solution, and ideally a solution for Safari.